# Why is there no dispatch_group_sync function for groups in GCD?

Tags: ios, objective-c, objective-c-blocks, grand-central-dispatch

It is said that :

> GCD lets us create groups, which allow you to place your tasks in one place, run all of them, and get a notification at the end from GCD. Those group blocks of code together ensure that all of them get **executed** by GCD **one by one**, as dependencies of one another.

As those blocks are getting executed one by one, then technically GCD function for dispatch_group should be  **dispatch_group_sync** not **dispatch_group_async**.

Thanks in advance for great explanation.

Comment: i would say the sync vs async refers to it being executed on the main thread (in sync with the ui) or asynchronous to the main thread

Comment: If I am not  wrong then you mean to say that, the tasks performed by dispatch_group is executed asynchronously relative to main thread.but what if I post all the group blocks on main queue only, then those tasks will be executed one by one one on main thread, will it executed on main thread synchronously or asynchronously ?

Comment: if you use sync and give it the main queue, it will block the main thread and run the blocks on the main thread, then unblock the main thread when they are done. if you use async and give it the main queue, it will not block the main thread, then wait for the current run loop to end, then execute the blocks, then run the next run loop once the blocks have finished. I cant guarantee what im saying is true, but from my understanding this is how it works. in short, sync will block the current thread while it does its stuff, async wont

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because here **async** is relative to the thread(Common main tread) that the block is submitted.

You do not need to **sync** groups to that thread,you just add code to that thread,code is executed one by one.

Besides,with dispatch group.

- You can let tasks execute one by one if you add those tasks to a serial queue(`DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL`).
- You can also let tasks execute concurrent if you add those tasks to a concurrent queue(`DISPATCH_QUEUE_CONCURRENT`).

Comment: besides whats the difference between DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL and dispatch_group? Both looks somewhat similar to me.